# How do I check if a key in a hash table has a certain hashcode?

Tags: java, data-structures

For example, ht.put("A", 0); has a hashcode of 65. How would I search the hashtable to see whether a key with a hashcode of 65 exists?

Comment: Iterate through the key set and check.

Comment: Why are you interested in the hashcode, instead of the actual full value?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis By doing so you're losing the benefit of hashcodes being split into buckets within the table, allowing for fast lookups.

Comment: I thought it would be faster to zone in on a hashcode than to search the whole table for a key. This is my understanding. I didn't write my own implementation

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do. If you're writing your own hash table, you should use the hash code (in the hash table's internals). If you're *using* a hash table, the hash code (and equality) should capture the attributes you're interested in; Thus to search for a key you should be able to just do `table.get(key)`. If that doesn't work for you, please explain in detail what you're dealing with and what you're trying to do. Possibly in a new question.

Comment: I will try to address the issue here. Thanks for the help thus far. Ultimately, I am importing two text files for the hashtable part of a wordsearch solving program. One file has a file of words that are identifiable in the wordsearch (A). The other file is a large dictionary (B). I am inserting the words from text file A into the hashtable. Then I am checking see whether or not the imported words from text file B equals the hashcode in A.

Comment: And *why* are you checking for *hashcode* equality? From the rest of your description, you seem to be interested into whether the *strings* match. That hashing even exists is of no interest and only an implementation detail of the hash table. Unless your intent is to search for hash *collisions*, but the rest of your description doesn't sound like that.

Comment: Do you know of any examples of the checking whether strings match (a link or video would be wonderful)? I struggling to write this on my own

Comment: @user3535029 Just use `get()` and pass the string in.

Comment: You check whether strings match using `someString.equals(someOtherString)`, although that's another question that I'm not sure whether you actually want the answer to or you just think you do.

Comment: Just checked this out and got it all to work. From my understanding you don't get credit for continuing to comment so thank you for all the help. I really need to get better at reading API's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a class whose hashcode is the code in question:

```
public class HashCodeWrapper {
    private final int hashCode;
    public HashCodeWrapper(int hashCode){
        this.hashCode = hashCode;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return hashCode;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){ return this.hashCode == o.hashCode(); }
}
```

You can then pass this into [`Hashtable#get(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29).

Note that there may be hash collisions, in this case the result will be any with this hashcode. However, with a null-check this is more than enough to check for the existence of this hashcode.

Comment: This tells you whether there's a key which hashes to the same bucket, in other words whether there is a key whose hash value is congruent to `hashCode` modulo the bucket array size.

Comment: By the way, I remain unconvinced whether this is a robust solution. It's certainly clever, but I can't prove that it's correct in all circumstances. Also, of course, whether this is the actual problem OP should be trying to solve.

Comment: @delnan Wait, no. If you look at [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java#354) you will see that there is indeed a hashCode *and* an equals comparison. Therefore, the original would still hold if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @delnan First. And source seems to address the second somewhat.

Comment: Ah yes, for that specific implementation it would work. But note that the hash code comparison is far from guaranteed: It's merely an optimization. Some hash tables are designed for keys with very cheap hashing and equality and accordingly don't store the hash of existing keys; those tables wouldn't do a hash comparison. This is also my main concern in my second comment: There's a large design space for hash tables and this approach possibly depends on implementation details.

Comment: OK, that's a valid point. I'll leave this up for reference in case the OP or another visitor wishes to use this approach.

Comment: @delnan: Looking at the source code this should work, IMO, because of the impelmentation of the `equals` and the invocation of `Hashtable#get(Object)` method. It uses the hash code of the object to calculate the index of the bucket but not matter what it cannot change the hash code of the object.

Comment: @BheshGurung There was an earlier version of the answer with an `equals` that unconditionally returned `true`. (Does that make sense as a reply?)

Comment: @delnan: Actually, what I was trying to indicate was that for any implementation that respects what's specified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) for the `hashCode` and `equals` methods, this approach should work.

Comment: @delnan Only the latter version would work. *The formal contract for `HashCode#get` uses `equals` as a check*, namely `key.equals(k)`. Therefore, a compliant HashTable *must* return the value if I pass this hashCodeWrapper. HashCode and equals work together (hashcode equality implies `equals` returning true), and no contracts of hashcode and equals are violated by this wrapper.

Comment: @BheshGurung To double-check, you're talking about the version whose `equals` returns `true` unconditionally? In that case, consider again: There is no guarantee that `equals` is only called for objects with equal hash code (at least there isn't in the page you link to). Furthermore, that version violates the part of the `hashCode` contract that states "If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.".

Comment: @hexafraction It's entirely possible the current version is guaranteed to work. I just wouldn't put my reputation behind that claim, it's too fickle an issue for me to answer off hand and not interesting enough to pursue in depth. Edit: Could you be more specific?

Comment: @delnan: I am talking about the current version. And I understand what you are trying to say is wrong when returning true unconditionally. But don't you think this will always work in case of a proper hash-based implementation? If not, why?

Comment: @delnan That was in response to one of your older comments, it may be disregarded now

Comment: @BheshGurung My stance on the correctness of the *current* version has been discussed to exhaustion in prior comments.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP shouldn't use this approach for the problem they're trying to solve (and instead just use a `contains`), but I believe it is the correct answer for the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you have to traverse map's `entrySet()` and check each `key()`'s `hashCode()` against some value you want to check presense, `65` in your example:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public boolean hashCodePresent(int hashCode) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (mapEntry.getKey().hashCode() == hashCode) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```